# copy resources from jar into war with changed directory structure

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have 2 Projects i.e Project A.war and Project B.jar .

Project B is added as a dependency in project A.

Currenctly Project B has some scripts in particular folder structure. I include these scripts in Project B.jar using maven includes.

I want to copy these files in Project A.war in another folder structure.

Is this correct way to do or can it be done in better way.

My final aim is to copy the scripts from Project B to Project A.war in differenct folder stucture.

Comment: The question's not clear to me. You've got it working, and want to know if this is the best approach? Or are you asking how to do it?

Comment: I want know how to copy scripts from Project B to Project A.war in differenct folder stucture

Comment: Need a few more specifics I think: 1) where the scripts live in both the src tree and where they end up in project B 2) where you want them in the war 3) the part of the pom where you "include these scripts in Project B.jar using maven includes"

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. First use unpack then use resources. Thanks for help

Comment: can you please send more detailed information how you solved it?